# Should websites with only global ip addresses be ssl?

Tags: apache, ssl, web

The website operating only with global ip address（There is no domain name）.
Will this be indexed by search engines? Is it possible to introduce ssl on this site? 
Since it is not currently set to https, we are worried that there may be a possibility of leakage of login information etc（I can not understand how much this risk is）.

Comment: Why aren't you using a name? HTTPS is supposed to be used with names, not IPs. While you can technically get from some CA a certificate for an IP address this will be an impedance mismatch in HTTPS, so really not the route to go. Whatever you are trying to protect (being indexed, login information, etc. from your post but that is not clear), thinking that not having a name will protect you in some way is wrong.

Comment: This website is used only in the family. Therefore, I do not bother to spend money to acquire a domainname. Can I encrypt without acquiring a domainname?

Comment: "I do not bother to spend money to acquire a domainname."  you can find domain names in the $5-$10 ballpark sometimes even less with promotions and such; and I am sure you pay more than that for webhosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [get an SSL certificate for an IP address](https://www.ssl247.co.uk/ssl-certificates/type/ip); this will achieve two things.

Firstly, it confirms to visitors that the IP address hasn't been hijacked - it belongs to the organisation that bought the IP address, not *evil_hax0r* who has somehow hijacked that address.

Secondly, it encrypts communication between visitor and server.

You should *not* depend on being invisible in search engines - this strategy is called [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and is widely discredited. There are all sorts of bots trawling the internet looking for vulnerable machines, and they will find you, even if you're not in Google.

Secondly, yes, Google will *probably* find you - if there's a link to your IP address anywhere on the Internet, Google will find it. You can create a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) to control what happens next.

Finally, should you do this? [Google thinks so](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/encrypt-in-transit/why-https). It's [free for many use cases](https://letsencrypt.org/).

Comment: letsencrypt won't give certs for IP addresses.

Comment: "not evil_hax0r who has somehow hijacked that address." I do not see how. In case of a BGP hijack, first your client has no way to know it needs to get a certificate when it will not get one anymore (HSTS is for names, not IPs) and second even if you force that, the hijacker can send its own certificate, even get one from a CA during the BGP hijack. So something at the TLS layer can not fully protect you from attacks at the IP level.

Comment: "Secondly, it encrypts communication between visitor and server. "  you can do encryption, including with TLS even without a certificate. A certificate is more a mean to authenticate the remote, which is the most important/primary need, over encrypting to it (because otherwise you may be encrypting stuff but sending it to someone you do not know/trust).

Answer (score 0):

> Will this be indexed by search engines

If they find your ip/port, yes.

You can make a self signed certificate to encrypt the network traffic. You will get a warning when visiting the site though (cert not trusted).

Buying a cert, which is trusted, should be possible but i don't know any resellers.

Comment: You can self-sign a cert for the IP but I don't know of any CAs that will issue a certificate on a bare IP; they're normally assigned to a Fully Qualified Domain Name.

Comment: "If they find your ip/port, yes." In IPv4 it is not very complicated to scan all IPs, a lot of people/organizations are doing this regularly. And port 443 is customary for HTTPS.

Comment: @CD001 "I don't know of any CAs that will issue a certificate on a bare IP" I agree but not the the CABForum requirements specifically deal with the case of certificates on IP addresses. See https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.0.pdf  section "3.2.2.5.
Authentication for an IP Address" which starts with "For each IP Address listed in a Certificate, the CA SHALL confirm that, " etc. So certainly rare specially for HTTPS as not designed for it, but otherwise certificates exist for IP addresses. For example in the RIR world to secure IP blocks.

Comment: From RFC6125: Some certification authorities issue server certificates based on IP addresses, but preliminary evidence indicates that such certificates are a very small percentage (less than 1%) of issued certificates.  Furthermore, IP addresses are not necessarily reliable identifiers for application services because of the existence of private internets, host mobility, multiple interfaces on a given host, Network Address Translators resulting in different addresses for a host from different locations on the network, the practice of grouping many host together behind a single IP address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be indexed. If you want to avoid this, there are several options. The defacto standard is to add a robots.txt file and define what you want with the robots exclusion standard.

Yes, you can use SSL on a public IP address.

The risk with using un-encrypted login is that the browser will send the login information as plain text. HTTP stands for Hyper Text Transfer Protocol, all the information is sent over the internet in clear text form. This means someone can intercept and read the information.

Adding SSL sends the hypertext as an encrypted message.